# Factoring over a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Consider $f=x^4-2\in \mathbb{F}_3[x]$, the field with three elements. I want to find the Galois group of this polynomial.

> Is there an easy or slick way to factor such a polynomial over a finite field?

Comment: It's a quartic, so first look for roots and then check the quadratics. There aren't that many possibilities for roots or irreducible quadratics, so you can do this pretty quickly without too much trouble.

Comment: @BrettFrankel, like this? $x^{4}-2=(x^{2}+\sqrt{2})(x^{2}-\sqrt{2})$. I can do this over $\mathbb{Q}$, but I am not sure what $\sqrt{2}$ corresponds to in $\mathbb{F}_{3}$.

Comment: Well, there's a sign error. Also, 2 has no squareroot in $\mathbb{F}_3$. What I meant was, make a list of the irreducible quadratics over $\mathbb{F}_3$ and check whether any of them divide $f$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Recall that over $\mathbb{F}_q$, the polynomial $x^{q^n} - x$ is precisely the product of all irreducible polynomials of degree dividing $n$. The following then gives a straightforward algorithm to determine the degrees of the irreducible factors of a polynomial $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$:

- Initialize $g(x) := \frac{f(x)}{\gcd(f(x), f'(x))}$ (this removes repeated factors) and $n := 1$.
- Compute $\gcd(g(x), x^{q^n} - x)$ via the Euclidean algorithm. This is the product of all irreducible factors of $f$ of degree $n$.
- Set $g(x) := \frac{g(x)}{\gcd(g(x), x^{q^n} - x)}$ and $n := n+1$.
- Repeat.

In this case by inspection $f$ has no linear factors so we only have to check for quadratic factors, hence we only have to compute $\gcd(x^4 - 2, x^9 - x)$. But again by inspection,
$$(x^4 - 2)(x^4 + 2) = x^8 - 1$$

so in fact $x^4 - 2$ must be a product of two (distinct) irreducible quadratics.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thanks for the great answer.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, there is a straightforward, mindless thing to do:

- Is $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{F}_3$?

  - If yes, then does $\sqrt{2}$ have a square root in $\mathbb{F}_3$?

    - If yes, then the splitting field of $f$ is $\mathbb{F}_3$
    - If no, then the splitting field of $f$ is $\mathbb{F}_9 (\cong \mathbb{F}(\sqrt[4]{2}))$
  - If no, then $\mathbb{F}_9 \cong \mathbb{F}_3(\sqrt{2})$. Does $\sqrt{2}$ have a square root in $\mathbb{F}_9$?

    - If yes, then the splitting field of $f$ is $\mathbb{F}_9$
    - If no, then the splitting field of $f$ is $\mathbb{F}_{81} (\cong \mathbb{F}_3(\sqrt[4]{2})$

And in all cases, you can refine the argument to find all of the roots, and/or to find the factors of $f$.

We can get a bit of a shortcut by observing all of the fourth roots of unity have to be in the splitting field of $f$, so $\mathbb{F}_9$ has to be involved.

We can get even more of a shortcut by observing, for $x \in \overline{\mathbb{F}_3} \setminus 0$:

- $x \in \mathbb{F}_3$ if and only if $x^2 = 1$
- Therefore $x^4 \in \mathbb{F}_3$ if and only if $x^8 = 1$
- $x \in \mathbb{F}_9$ if and only if $x^8 = 1$
- Therefore $x^4 \in \mathbb{F}_3$ if and only if $x \in \mathbb{F}_9$

If we just want the Galois group, we can stop here. :)

Answer (score 2):

The coefficients are reduced modulo 3, so
$$
x^4-2=x^4-3x^2+1=(x^4-2x^2+1)-x^2=(x^2-1)^2-x^2=(x^2+x-1)(x^2-x-1).
$$

It is easy to see that neither $x^2+x-1$ nor $x^2-x-1$ have any roots any $F_3$. As they are both quadratic, the roots are in $F_9$. Therefore the Galois group is $Gal(F_9/F_3)$, i.e. cyclic of order two.